# Create a custom KSP in Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-registry, certificate, regedit

The setup: Certificates are stored on a server/HSM and domain users have a certificate for digital signatures.
I want to configure Windows to request password and OTP whenever the user tries to use a certificate stored on the server (using a separate custom app), for example when digitally signing a PDF in Adobe Reader.

I know that there should be a registered provider in the windows registry, but i can't seem to find any info about what registries are needed and what values.